# Find search and replace using sed

Tags: search, replace, sed, find

I found the following command to be excellent for finding and replacing a word in the source code on the server via SSH,

where I want to replace the word 'word' with 'replacement_word' within the 'folder' folder.

```
# find <folder> -type f -exec sed -i 's/<word>/<replacement_word>/g' {} \;
```

However, how can I write this if the 'word' Im looking for contains a backslash ie '/Dev'

And how can I find and replace a large section of text that

a) Exactly matches
b) Contains 'like' matches.

Comment: What does this have to do with ssh? You can either escape the slash `\/` or use another marker for the `s///` command (`s!!!` or `s,,,` work just as well).

Comment: If your word / replacement_word values are in a variable, using double quotes would be required for your sed. I agree with Etan as well. # find <folder> -type f -exec sed -i "s#<word>#<replacement_word>#g" {} \;

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner so what would the exact command to replace '/Dev' with '/Development' be, for example?

Comment: `s,/Dev,Development,` or `s,/Dev,&elopment,` which uses `&` in the replacement which means `the part that matched`.

Comment: Thanks so much @EtanReisner and how about any ideas for finding and replacing larger blocks of code than just one word?

Comment: Same concept just more text. Also realize that `sed` is line-based so doing multi-line replacements is not trivial. Perhaps there are better tools for this job.

Comment: This problem seems solved by Etan, how does it close if there is no answer? Etan perhaps you can put your comment in an answer so Mark can select an answer.

Comment: yes happy to close this off and credit @EtanReisner with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any set of delimiter characters can be used in an `s///` command, not just the traditional `/`.

So you can use another marker for the `s///` command (`s!!!` or `s,,,` are both fairly common) or you can simply escape the slash `\/`.